# On Meteor, get data from a collection while looping on another

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have a collection that stores a list of posts users follow, and each user have its own document for it. It is structured like this:

```
{"_id": "12365",
"user": "123548" //user ID
"posts" : [
   {"postId": "225"},
   {"postId": "688"},
   {"postId": "55"},
   (...)
]}
```

`user` key refers to the `_id` of that user, created using `account` package.

I am trying to, while on user profile page, list all posts that user follow, but I am not being able to, by each `postId`, show that postTitle instead of its Id.

The HTML to render the list is like this:

```
<p class="title"><a href="#">{{postId}}</a></p>
```

And the template helper that get that user's followed posts is like this:

```
Template.singleUser.helpers({
    postsLibrary: function () {
        var postsLibraryContent = postsLibrary.find({
            user: Meteor.user();
        });
    },
});
```

How can I loop in the `posts` array from the collection of followed posts, but show each of the posts `title` that refer to each `postId`? Should I do it inside this helper above?

-- update --

Title is stored on a Collection of posts, like this:

```
{
    "_id": "9845", //same as postId from the other collection
    "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "author": "Peter Parker",
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it!

```
Template.singleUser.helpers({
  postsLibrary: function () {
    var data = [];

    //first we find all this current user postLibrary collection
    var postsLibraryContent =  PostsLibrary.find({
        user: this._id
    }).posts;

    //then for each item on `posts` array:
    for (var i = 0; i < postsLibraryContent.length; i++) {

        //get that array item postId value and store on a var
        var postId = postsLibraryContent[i].postId;

        //creates an array with the post data by searching for its _id
        postData = Posts.find({
            _id: postId
        }).fetch();            

        //and then push those data to an array above created
        data.push({
            postTitle: postData[0].title,
            postAuthor: postData[0].author
        })

    };

    //then return data array
    return data;

  }
});
```

And to render it on HTML:

```
{{#each postsLibrary}}
     <li>
         <p class="title"><a href="">{{postTitle}} - {{postAuthor}}</a></p>
     </li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Even though my answer works, probably it worths taking a look at this topic here for a better aproach:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913474/how-to-read-a-collection-that-depends-on-another-one-in-meteor?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Change your html from this

`<p class="title"><a href="#">{{postId}}</a></p>`

To this

```
{{#each posts}}
    <p class="title"><a href="#">{{postId}}</a></p>
{{/each}}
```

This will loop over the array posts.

Comment: Thanks, @JoshOne, but it is already like that. The problem is that it returns the `postId` itself, and not the post title. The question was how to use this `postId` to get the post title and display there where today shows the `{{postId}}`.

Comment: Ok, I see. Please update your question to show where the Title is stored. The only reference to title I see is a class of title.